# How to have separate build:bundle for linux and windows for my node project?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am very new to node.js and npm. I was trying to setup an open source project locally on my windows and I got this error

`'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

So I edited `build:bundle` in package.json, `SET NODE_ENV=xyz` from `NODE_ENV=xyz`. It installed the project properly then.

My question is, Is there a way to tell npm to use `SET NODE_ENV=xyz` on windows and `NODE_ENV=xyz` on linux/mac, so that I can create a fix without breaking the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Install and use the package named [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

`$ npm install --save-dev cross-env`

> Run scripts that set and use environment variables across platforms

You can then use one syntax, so the `build:bundle` script will be something like this:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "build:bundle": "cross-env NODE_ENV=xyz ...",
  ...
}
```